# How to resolve SOQL query error: ''Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported"

Tags: soql, community, api

Here is my SOQL query below in Alteryx application where I have to extract the Id from Contact object which has two level sub-selects. I could only make the SOQL query to work for 1 level of subselect but not more.

Are there any workarounds for this? It would be of great help if someone can edit my code to make it work.

```
Select Id from Contact c
Where
c.Id in
(SELECT 
contact__c
FROM 
VIN__c  v
where v.Id in
(SELECT 
vin__c
FROM 
Mileage_Reading__c
WHERE 
CreatedDate >= 2020-06-01T00:00:00Z AND  CreatedDate < 2020-07-01T00:00:00Z))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go a level deep in NESTED Subquery in SOQL. This is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)

> You cannot nest a semi-join or anti-join statement in another semi-join or anti-join statement.

> You can use semi-joins and anti-joins in the main WHERE statement, but not in a subquery WHERE statement.

You can split the above queries into multiple. In Salesforce apex language, this is how you do,

```
List<Mileage_Reading__c>  lstMileageReading = [SELECT vin__c FROM Mileage_Reading__c WHERE CreatedDate >= 2020-06-01T00:00:00Z AND  CreatedDate < 2020-07-01T00:00:00Z];

List<Contact> lstcontact = [Select Id FROM Contact c
  WHERE
  c.Id in
 (SELECT 
  contact__c
  FROM 
  VIN__c  v
  WHERE v.Id IN :lstMileageReading)]:
```

If you need this from a third party REST Service, you can create an apex class that exposes this as a [REST Utility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm). Then you can invoke the apex rest service as an API.

**Alteryx Connector**

You can a [Select](https://help.alteryx.com/10.1/AlteryxSelect.htm) tools and  [Join](https://help.alteryx.com/2018.2/Join.htm) tool to acheive this.

Comment: I have tried using your code. It gives me this error, "unexpected token: List"

Comment: where are you trying? Dev Console apex anonymous window?

Comment: Its an apex code and not completely SOQL. Are you using this SOQL in apex or from any other system invoking salesforce REST API?

Comment: I am using Salesforce connector in Alteryx. I have querying data from prod enviroment with read only access.

Comment: @mysticmind In that case you have to execute these queries one by one and hold the result in a variable and use the variable list in second SOQL. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If you don't mind, can you help me how to hold the variable in first soql?

Comment: You can use two Select tool and a Join tool in Alteryx to join them together.